# Post request is getting converted into two GET requests. I Can't believe on my eyes

Tags: angular

I am doing nothing, just this small code is running when I click on a button. The purpose is to make a post request.

```
  changePassword() {
    let changePasswordUrl = this.constantsService.updatePassword();
    let body = {
      old_password: this.old_password,
      new_password: this.new_password
    };
    this.httpClient.post(changePasswordUrl, body)
      .catch((e: any) => {
        console.log(e);
        return _throw('error');
      })
      .subscribe((val) => {
        console.log(val);
      });
  }
```

But When open a network tab I see **this**:

0 post request and 2 GET request.
**Following are screenshots of network tab.**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help will be deeply appreciated

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in a StackBlitz?

Comment: Let me do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was just a slash (`/`) at the end of the URL.
Meaning, if I make a `POST` request with `'/'` in the end, I am getting a success `POST` response. However, if I get make the request without `'/'` in the end, I am getting the behaviour described in the question (two `GET` requests). It's not something I have seen previously.

I called the backend dev in my team and showed him this behaviour, even he couldn't understand why is this happening. He is using `Tastypie` in the backend.

If our understanding develops, I will update it here.